# How to download slack audio clips using python

Tags: python-3.x, audio, download, slack-api

I'm looking for a way to download audio clips exported to a Slack channel using Python. Once the audio clip is posted in a channel, a private url gets created. I'm looking for an option to download the audio clip using this private url (url_private_download field from slack) of the file. Below is the code that I've tried. But, it's not creating a valid audio file.

```
slack_token = 'MY Slack Token'
url = 'https://files.slack.com/files-tmb/<<ID>>/download/audio_message_audio.mp4'
res = requests.get(url, headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer %s' % slack_token})
fname = "test.wav"
print(os.path)
assert not os.path.exists(name), print("File already exists. Please remove/rename and re-run")
out_file = wave.open(fname, "w")
out_file.setnchannels(1)
out_file.setsampwidth(2)
out_file.setframerate(44100.0)
out_file.writeframes(res.content)
out_file.close()
```

Error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/Users/ramuchowdam/Desktop/speechtotext.py", line 24, in 
> audio_text = r.listen(fname)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/speech_recognition/**init**.py",
> line 464, in listen
> assert isinstance(source, AudioSource), "Source must be an audio source" AssertionError: Source must be an audio source

Please let me know what is wrong with above code

Comment: The part downloading mp4 file from Slack looks good. The wave conversion should have some issues. Using ffmpeg may be an easier way to do so.